# Iran threatening to attack Dubai

Tags: united-states, economy, armed-conflict, iran, history

Hours ago Iran had threatened to attack Dubai, referring to Dubai as "America's leg" because of our U.S. owned oil businesses and shipments there.

When Iran threatened to attack U.S. troops or civilians, I noticed Trump and his circle was quick to respond back with threats. Though now oil money is at stake.

So my question is: Has there been any responses by U.S. powers regarding the Dubai threats? If not, do you have examples of how the U.S. has responded to legitimate threats of economic warfare as opposed to legitimate threats of U.S. troops and civilians?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any specific US response to the Dubai threat... By the way, this was not made explicit in the "leg" statement, but [rather](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/01/iran-fires-rockets-forces-iraq-latest-updates-200107235228432.html) in a separate IRGC statement, which also threatened Israel:

> Iranian President Hassan Rouhani told the US that Washington might have "cut off the arm" of Soleimani but America's "leg" in the region would be cut off in response, Iran's Fars news agency reported.
>
> [...]
>
> The Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps (IRGC) warned on their Telegram channel that in the event that Iranian soil is bombed, they would launch a third wave of attacks to destroy Dubai and Haifa.

Trump however has already [warned](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/iran-news-war-us-trump-strike-back-twitter-latest-a9271476.html) Iran in general terms that the US will respond perhaps in a "disproportionate manner" to any Iranian actions, after striking Suleimani.

See also a [related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46213/are-there-any-public-opinion-polls-in-the-us-on-them-starting-military-action-ag?noredirect=1&lq=1) in which the answer happens to touch on US public support for a US military response to the [alleged] Iranian attack against the Saudi oil facilities. (Yes, Trump might not be entirely bound by public opinion, but it's probably informative to what level of response he might choose in case non-US but allied facilities get struck in the Gulf.)

After the Iranian missile strike of Wednesday, which resulted in no casualties, Trump [said](https://www.latimes.com/politics/story/2020-01-08/trump-address-iran-missile-strike-us-base-full-remarks) the Iran "appears to be standing down". In that rather lengthy speech, he did not make any comments on IRGC's threats against Dubai or Haifa, as far as I can tell. He did also say

> We are independent, and we do not need Middle East oil.